# How to only format data if column has data ,else dont do anything?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to format the phone number that is in this format 5551234567, but some of the columns will be empty. If I don't do a CASE, when I ran the query the result will show up with empty parentheses. The query runs, but can not get the phone number to format as i have in the SQL code. e.g (555) 123-4567.

```
 SELECT shade,name,
 CASE WHEN  phone = '' OR LENGTH (TRIM (phone)) = 0 THEN phone
 WHEN phone LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN  
 '(' || '' || SUBSTRING(phone,1,3) || ')' || ' ' || SUBSTRING(phone,4,3) || '-' || SUBSTRING(phone,7,4) 
 ELSE phone END AS phone,
 FROM mytable
```

Also trying to check if its all numbers, otherwise dont do anything and just display how it is! Thanks for looking!

Comment: Does the PHONE column allow NULL ?  check your table definition. If it allows NULL then code your case statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to accomplish what I was looking for and I hope it can help others as well:

```
 SELECT shade,name,
 CASE WHEN  phone = '' OR LENGTH (TRIM (phone)) = 0 THEN phone
 WHEN length(regexp_substr(phone, '[[:digit:]]+',1, 1) ) = 10
 THEN '(' || '' || SUBSTRING(phone,1,3) || ')' || ' ' || SUBSTRING(phone,4,3)    || '-' || SUBSTRING(phone,7,4) 
 ELSE phone END AS phone,
 FROM mytable
```